# ErrorMissingEmailAddress error when accessing other user's Exchange mailbox by EWS

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm using EWS Managed API to read emails from Inbox and subfolders. When I connect as the mailbox owner with username & password auth it all works fine, but when I connect as a service account using windows auth I get an error when accessing the subfolders. The service account has been granted Full Access to the mailbox it's connecting to. The service account doesn't have its own mailbox. The error is:

```
Problem encountered while retrieving the email from exchange. Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: When making a request as an account that does not have a mailbox, you must specify the mailbox primary SMTP address for any distinguished folder Ids.
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.InternalThrowIfNecessary()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at MyMethod_That_Calls_ExchangeServer_FindItems(folderId, view)
```

This is a pretty common error to get when you're using delegate access to a mailbox (i.e. not connecting to a mailbox you own) and you connect to a Well Known mailbox without specifying the mailbox owner. There's an easy fix to that: you create a `FolderId` object using a `Mailbox` object with the primary smtp address of the mailbox you want to connect to, e.g.

```
var theMailboxEmailAddress = "johnsmith@example.com";
var folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
                      new Mailbox(theMailboxEmailAddress);
var items = myExchangeService.FindItems(folderId, anItemView);
```

However, my case isn't that easy. I am specifying the mailbox where I can but I'm getting the error when I'm calling `FindItems` on the subfolder. There's no way to specify the mailbox when accessing the subfolder, because it should work without that.

According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn641957(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_explicitewsma) ('Explicit access and EWS') the suggested method is:

- Start by using '[explicit access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn641957(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_explicitewsma)': call `FindFolder()` with a `DistinguishedFolderId` (aka `WellKnownFolderName`), passing a `MailBox` param to identify the mailbox owner.

  - That works fine for me, I'm able to get a list of the folders beneath Inbox and get the folder `ItemId` values
- Then use '[implicit access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn641957(v=exchg.150).aspx#Anchor_3)': call `service.FindItems(folderId, view)` passing in the folderId retrieved from the previous step. This fails for me, which is surprising.

When I look at the EWS trace I can see that there are no DistinguishedFolderIds being sent in my `FindItems()` request. Here is the call that fails:

```
Trace type: EwsRequest
Trace message: <Trace Tag="EwsRequest" Tid="13" Time="2016-10-13 12:50:05Z" Version="15.00.0913.015">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP2" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
        <m:ItemShape>
          <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
          <t:AdditionalProperties>
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject" />
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:DateTimeReceived" />
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="message:IsRead" />
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="message:From" />
            <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="InternetHeaders" PropertyName="X-MyApp-MailId" PropertyType="String" />
          </t:AdditionalProperties>
        </m:ItemShape>
        <m:IndexedPageItemView MaxEntriesReturned="6" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning" />
        <m:SortOrder>
          <t:FieldOrder Order="Ascending">
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:DateTimeReceived" />
          </t:FieldOrder>
        </m:SortOrder>

<!-- Note below there's no DistinguishedFolderId, so nowhere to specify the mailbox -->

        <m:ParentFolderIds>
          <t:FolderId Id="AAMkAGU2NWRkNjYxLTI3YjktNDFkMi04ZmNlLWI0M2FmMGVmYzBhYwAuAAAAAAD/Z9M6ia69S5l65fo6tjEaAQAoQBtCK9L9S4ux7hB0Qcw/AAAIZFKVAAA=" />
        </m:ParentFolderIds>


      </m:FindItem>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
</Trace>
```

Here's the failure response:

```
Trace type: EwsResponse
Trace message: <Trace Tag="EwsResponse" Tid="13" Time="2016-10-13 12:50:05Z" Version="15.00.0913.015">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
      <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="0" MajorBuildNumber="847" MinorBuildNumber="31" Version="V2_8" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <m:FindItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
        <m:ResponseMessages>
          <m:FindItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
            <m:MessageText>When making a request as an account that does not have a mailbox, you must specify the mailbox primary SMTP address for any distinguished folder Ids.</m:MessageText>
            <m:ResponseCode>ErrorMissingEmailAddress</m:ResponseCode>
            <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
          </m:FindItemResponseMessage>
        </m:ResponseMessages>
      </m:FindItemResponse>
    </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
</Trace>
```

In the example above I was specifying ExchangeServerVersion Exchange2010_SP2 but I've tried also with Exchange2013. I'm connecting to an Exchange 2013 server.

A colleague tried the same thing using EWSEditor and got the same error. I've not double-checked that yet, but if so it suggests an EWS problem or an easy mistake to make when using the API.

Also posted on MSDN forums [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/36a4aa1d-506e-4feb-a09a-a6ebb925d763/2013-ews-ewsma-c-windows-ews-error-when-calling-finditems-on-subfolder-in-another?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment).

**UPDATE 13-Oct-16:**

Based on this [Handling delegation-related errors in EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn720423(v=exchg.150).aspx) article I'm now wondering if this is a 'by design' limitation of Exchange. i.e. that if you want to look in non-well-known folders in an inbox you must have a mailbox, else it can't manage the permissions or something like that. In that article it says for `ErrorMissingEmailAddress` occurs when "Make a request using a delegate account that does not have a mailbox." and to handle it by "Adding a mailbox to the delegate’s account."

I'll check tomorrow whether adding a mailbox to the service account (which is otherwise not used at all) resolves the problem.

Comment: would this service be reading your exchange inbox or everybody's it it's everybody's then think about why it's not working.. it's quite obvious don't you think..?

Comment: @MethodMan - are you alluding to but not quite stating that it might be a permissions issue? No, it's not 'my' mailbox but it is one that the service account has permissions to, hence it works for reading folders within the Inbox. The service account has Full Access to the mailbox it's trying to read from. I really hope there's something quite obvious that I've missed as that'll be an easy fix: please tell!!

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the  (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data) FolderId class, it shows that when writing the Xml for the request, I believe it should include the Mailbox entry. It also shows that if you ToString() it, it should return the Folder ID and Mailbox ID. I'd suggest confirming the mailbox you are getting with "new Mailbox(theMailboxEmailAddress)" is not null and the value is what you expect. I also noticed the GetXmlElementName only returns DistinguishedFolderId when the FolderName within FolderId has a value - which from what I can see so far only occurs when the FolderId is created with a uniqueId string instead of a WellKnownFolderName.

```
    internal override string GetXmlElementName()
    {
        if (!this.FolderName.HasValue)
        {
            return "FolderId";
        }
        return "DistinguishedFolderId";
    }

    public FolderId(WellKnownFolderName folderName, Mailbox mailbox) : this(folderName)
    {
        this.mailbox = mailbox;
    }

    internal override void WriteAttributesToXml(EwsServiceXmlWriter writer)
    {
        if (this.FolderName.HasValue)
        {
            writer.WriteAttributeValue("Id", this.FolderName.Value.ToString().ToLowerInvariant());
            if (this.Mailbox != null)
            {
                this.Mailbox.WriteToXml(writer, "Mailbox");
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            base.WriteAttributesToXml(writer);
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (!this.IsValid)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        if (!this.FolderName.HasValue)
        {
            return base.ToString();
        }
        if (this.Mailbox != null && this.mailbox.IsValid)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} ({1})", this.folderName.Value, this.Mailbox.ToString());
        }
        return this.FolderName.Value.ToString();
    }
```

Update 1: 
I was still able to grab a quick trace. These were my results from some quick test code:

```
folder = New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox)
Dim v As New ItemView(10, 0, OffsetBasePoint.Beginning)
Dim f As FindItemsResults(Of Item) = oService.FindItems(folder, v)

    <m:ParentFolderIds>
      <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox" />
    </m:ParentFolderIds>



Dim box As New Mailbox(mailboxAddress)
folder = New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, box)
Dim v As New ItemView(10, 0, OffsetBasePoint.Beginning)
Dim f As FindItemsResults(Of Item) = oService.FindItems(folder, v)

  <m:ParentFolderIds>
      <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox">
        <t:Mailbox>
          <t:EmailAddress>****mailboxAddress****</t:EmailAddress>
        </t:Mailbox>
      </t:DistinguishedFolderId>
    </m:ParentFolderIds>
```

Update 2:

Confirmed that when using FolderId created with a uniqueId string, the trace is:

```
    <m:ParentFolderIds>
      <t:FolderId Id="AQMkADY5YmEzNGJmLTljN2QtNDIwNS1hMWU2LTg4ADM4NDAzMDcxMGEALgAAA83F9dM/SH5Lnnw/6ftMMB0BANfWBWp5+bpGsBoSfk3Km5IAAAINKgAAAA==" ChangeKey="AQAAABYAAADX1gVqefm6RrAaEn5NypuSAAC8Vr7C" />
    </m:ParentFolderIds>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll check those. Looking at the EWS xml spec the `ParentFolderIds` item https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa565998(v=exchg.150).aspx says you can either provide a FolderId OR a DistinguishedFolderId. The FolderId item doesn't allow for child elements so you can't specify a Mailbox for it. I'm now wondering if this is a 'by design' limitation of EWS. Will update question about that now...

Comment: A correction to my statement. I miswrote: I also noticed the GetXmlElementName only returns DistinguishedFolderId when the FolderName within FolderId has no value.  It is actually the opposite. It returns DistinguishedFolderId when FolderName has a value.

Comment: Right, so that confirms that it's only possible to specify a Mailbox when you have a DistinguishedFolderName. When you have a FolderId you can't specify a Mailbox.

Comment: Did a quick test and in my trace it did include the Mailbox. Not sure what I'm doing different than the original post. Updated my post with the trace results.

Comment: You're getting the `Mailbox` element when you *are* using a `DistinguishedFolderId`. That's working fine for me. My problem is there's no way to specify the Mailbox if I'm using the Folder Id with uniqueId string instead of the `DistinguishedFolderId`/name.

Comment: I understand now. I think between yesterday and today I must have confused the issue. You may be right about a design limitation then. As an alternative, you may be able to use the ImpersonatedUserId option, but that may require the service account to have additional rights. I haven't tried that in this scenario yet, just a thought that came to mind.

Comment: I agree that impersonation is another option, but it seems harder to configure and since my software is deployed on-prem at dozens of sites it's a much more difficult route to go down asking IT to configure impersonation than configuring delegate access. Impersonation also, I believe, means you can do quite a bit more so it's more serious granting of rights.  And thanks for the input - good to have another set of eyes checking if I'm just doing something stupid!